# How to find the pair of two of edges which, removed from a graph, makes it disconnected?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

How to find ALL the pair of two edges which, removed from a graph, makes it disconnected?
I was thinking about a O(M * (N + M )) algorithm, and I am wondering if there is a better algorithm.
Thanks in advice!

Comment: Please check [about] and [help/on-topic]. This question seems more suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking here, but I guarantee you won't find any sub-linear time algorithm for this task.

If you have $O(M+(N+M )) = O(N+M)$ algorithm,  be happy about it :).

In the general case, every set of two edges could leave the graph disconnected so you'd need $\Omega(M^2)$ just to output the result (think of a cycle on $N$ vertices).

Comment: N <= 100000 and M <= 300000
O( M + (N + M ) ) != O ( N + M ) I guarantee

Comment: Hmm, I guess you misunderstand what the $O$ stands for (or possibly in the wrong forum).

No matter what are M,N values, $M+(N+M) = 2M + N < 2(M+N)$.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Ahhh, I wrote O( M + (N + M ) ? Sorry, I ment O ( M * ( M + N ) )...I will edit the question as well. Sorry again!